# javascript stubbornness

Tags: javascript

I create two sets of code. Both seem the same but one is working and one is not.

http://jsfiddle.net/tM9Gu/ is not working

http://jsfiddle.net/gDxqj/ is working

Working means when you click on "other" a new textfield opens. Not working means it doesn't.

What is the difference?

```
<div class="rButtons">
    <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="10" onclick="uncheck();" />10
    <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="20"  onclick="uncheck();" />20
    <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="other" onclick="check(this);"/>other
    <input type="text" id="other_field" name="other_field" onblur="checktext(this);"/>
</div>
```

Comment: In the first case, the functions are defined inside the `load` event handler (look at the left side, it says `onLoad` in the first select element). That means the functions are not global and cannot be found by inline event handlers (error message: `Uncaught ReferenceError: check is not defined `). In the second case, the script is directly put in the head (`no wrap (head)`) and are therefore global. jsFiddle is like any other tool, you have to make yourself familiar with it before you use it.

Comment: you meant that in one `fiddle` `hidden input` is shown and on the other it is not shown ?

Comment: @FelixKling you are right.. could you please explain how can i use the working fiddle to my website??

Comment: Just add the code to your page. You can have a look at the source of the result panel in jsFiddle and see how they do it.

Comment: @FelixKling 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
the javascript code is inside this file "functions.js" and the above line is in head.. Still this is not working on my website??

Comment: Then something else might be wrong. Maybe the file is not found, you have syntax errors in your code, maybe the functions are not global (again), etc. It could be anything. Stackoverflow is not a debugging service, you have to do that yourself. Look at the console for error messages, check whether the file was loaded, etc.

Comment: @Ashis It is a good practice to put all script tags before closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: I got to learn something very good and excellent today.. I got it working.. CSS it shall be hidden as shown here.. Thanx guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It happens because in the [following fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tM9Gu/) you have your JavaScript code inside `onLoad` method, which *"closes"* all your functions inside that method.

[image: onLoad]

*Primitive:*

```
function onLoad() {
   function func1() { ... }
}

func1();  // out of scope: will cause an error
```

Comment: wow... 
How can i use it in my coding?? cuz using jsfiddle code on your website is not simple..

Comment: @Ashis jsfiddle is for testing small code snippets for sanity testing, not for pasting your entire website into and running.

Comment: @jbabey i already know what u told me... and i have not pasted my website there just a chunk of code..

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
the javascript code is inside this file "functions.js" and the above line is in head.. Still this is not working on my website??

Comment: How are you testing your page?  Are you viewing it in a separate browser window?